# Data fit for linear regression model

Tags: regression, categorical-data, dataset, model, linear

I'm dealing with data of a survey for the very first time. I must to build  a linear regression model as a task but i'm in doubt in the choice of the dependent variable. I have a likert scale of preferencies in someone's buying and frequency of buying associated with a product.

I would like to build a lineare regression model choosing as Y,the frequency of buying associated with a product. This variable is divided into classes like this: 1=always; 2=2-3 times in a week; 3= once in a week; 4= once in a month; 5=almost never

For another product this variables shows up like this:
never,almost never,once in a month,2 times in a month, but the opinion to express was free to give.

Is it okay if i choose one of these two(especially i would like the first one) variables as Y (dependent variable) in my linear regression model?  I thought that classe should have been continuous inside them and among them ,which is not the case with the first variable.

Note: i haven't studied other models except for the linear ones.
Thank you for your answering